# Не могу сформировать сложный Linq запрос(

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, linq

Есть две таблицы: КЛАССИФИКАЦИЯ содержит Имя, Главный класс и ВОПРОС содержит Вопрос, и Id классификации

Формируется иерархия из классов

Нужно сформировать linq запрос где будут выводится классификации у которых есть вопросы или есть вопросы в их подклассах?

Comment: Вы используете Entity Framework или что? И приведите в вопросе код упомянутых классов, а то ничего непонятно.

Comment: Главный класс - это что за поле? ParentId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуйте этот интерфейс в вашем родительском классе искомой классификации и вы получите  классификации у которых есть вопросы или есть вопросы в их подклассах.

```
    public  class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        List<Сlassification> classfications = new List<Сlassification>();
        List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
        questions.Add(new Question() { TextQuestion = "NotEmpty1" });
        questions.Add(new Question() { TextQuestion = "NotEmpty2" });
        questions.Add(new Question() { TextQuestion = "NotEmpty3" });
        questions.Add(new Question() { TextQuestion = string.Empty });
        questions.Add(new Question() { TextQuestion = "NotEmpty5" });
        List<IClassificationMy> result = questions.Where(f=> f.IsCorrect()).Select(f => f.MyClassification).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
    }
}
public class Сlassification : IClassificationMy
{
    public Сlassification()
    {

    }
    public object MainClass { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        MyClassification = new Сlassification();
    }
    public string TextQuestion { get; set; }
    public IClassificationMy MyClassification { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect() { return this.TextQuestion != string.Empty; }

}
```